# Ability to use new http client on each request when use HttpUser or FastHttpUser

Tags: python, http, python-requests, locust

Now each user can only use one http client to invoke api. One user share cookie and http session on all request.
But it not close to real scene
Is there way to support each user use new http client？

I tried create a HttpSession in task function, then each user can use a new http session when post request
But how to create a new fasthttpsession, is there any example or easy way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what FastHttpUser does here https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/09227b89276209b3d9ea4e5aebfd6c194c89d83b/locust/contrib/fasthttp.py#L340

So something like

```
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpSessio 
...
    # in your Users constructor or wherever you prefer
    self.fast_client = FastHttpSession(
        self.environment,
        base_url=self.host,
        network_timeout=self.network_timeout,
        connection_timeout=self.connection_timeout,
        max_redirects=self.max_redirects,
        max_retries=self.max_retries,
        insecure=self.insecure,
        concurrency=self.concurrency,
        user=self,
        client_pool=self.client_pool,
        ssl_context_factory=self.ssl_context_factory,
        headers=self.default_headers,
    )
```

Some (most) of those parameters wont be necessary/wont exist on an HttpUser object, so remove them as needed.